# How do I delete all discord roles the simple way?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a bunch of servers where I would like to delete all the roles that I previously made, but their number leaves much to be desired...

Instead of the traditional mentioning of said roles (which is flawed, and quite slow) I haven't been able to find out how to code it so the command can be run and all roles below the bot can be deleted, automatically.

code I came up with:

```
async def delrole(ctx, *, roles: discord.Role):
    for role in roles:
        try:
            await client.delete_role(ctx.message.guild, role)
        except discord.Forbidden:
            await client.say("Cannot delete this role!")
```

Any input would be much appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the old async version of discord.py, here's your fixed code:

```py
for role in ctx.guild.roles:
    try:
        await role.delete()
    except discord.Forbidden:
        await ctx.send(f'Cannot delete this role {role}')
```

Please read the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) of discord.py-rewrite

Comment: This is true, but doesn't really answer his question. He wanted to be able to remove all roles without having to mention them.

Comment: Edited the answer